# Connecting two phone numbers

Tags: sip

**Background** I am making a web app where the users input their phone numbers and it will randomly match two of them and exchange numbers (similar to chatroulette).

**Problem** Currently they are just given a number and have to manually enter it. It would be nice if I can automatically get the numbers to "call each other". Google Voice has a similar functionality because you can pick your phone and it will dial you and the other side and connect the call. Is there a service that allows me to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.phono.com/.  It's a jquery phone addin.

Hope it helps.